# Entity Framework 6: Load related entities with null or blank foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Parent has a collection of Child.
Child has a Foreign Key to Parent (ParentID), but that foreign key might by null / blank.
I want Entity Framework to always load Child with null / blank foreign key for all Parent.

```
public class Parent
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; } //Should load it's children AND children without foreign key.
}

public class Child
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string ParentID { get; set; } //This can be null / blank.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a ParentId, the child is what's known as an [orphan](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/06/02/deleting-orphans-with-entity-framework/). There's no way to link a child to a parent without a populated foreign key property.

If you're just looking to query the Children for records with a null or empty ParentId, do something like the following with your DbContext:

```
var orphans = myContext.Children.Where(child => String.IsNullOrEmpty(child.ParentId));
```

Comment: Is there any way to attach that to the property in Parent? Or some way to tell EntityFramework, that for 'Child' it should use that query?

Comment: @hatcyl Not automatically. You'll need to either run the code above in a ParentFactory and attach it to the Parent as a separate property, or do something that looks more like the Active Record pattern and have an instance of your DbContext newed up along with an instance of the Parent class, and run the code above in the constructor of Parent. Either way, you can't add the orphans to the Children collection. You'd need a separate property.